# Why does the printed char change when I use printf with %s and %c?

Tags: c, printf, format-specifiers

This is the code I have:

```
int main(){
    char *p = "koraytugay";
    printf("%s%i byte(s).\n",   "Size of variable p:"       ,sizeof(p));
    printf("%s%i byte(s).\n\n", "Size of what p points to:" ,sizeof(*p));

    char t[] = "koraytugay";
    printf("%s%i byte(s).\n",   "Size of variable t:"       ,sizeof(t));
    printf("%s%i byte(s).\n\n", "Size of what t points to:" ,sizeof(*t));

    printf("%s%c\n",    "Printing p[3]: ",  p[3]);
    printf("%s%c\n",    "Printing t[3]: ",  t[3]);

    printf("%s",*(&p));

}
```

and the output I get is:

```
Size of variable p:8 byte(s).
Size of what p points to:1 byte(s).

Size of variable t:11 byte(s).
Size of what t points to:1 byte(s).

Printing p[3]: a
Printing t[3]: a
koraytugay
```

When I change the last statement to:

```
printf("%c",*(&p));
```

The last line printed will be:

```
6
```

instead of

```
koraytugay
```

But why? I am expecting that it would print

```
k
```

?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't print `k` because it's expecting a `char` and you passed a `char *` so probably

```
printf("%c", **(&p));
```

will print `k`.

The type of `&p` is `char **` because it creates a pointer with the address of `p`, so `*(&p)` is exactly the same as `p`, hence to print `*(&p)` you need the `"%s"` specifier.

If you use the `"%c"` specifier with `*(&p)` it's evaluated as an integer so you can't predict what is going to be printed because it will depend on what is the value stored in the pointer.

Comment: @iharob Are you sure about this: The type of &p is char ** ? Isnt type of &p simply a long?

Comment: No, it's `char **`, what you might be confused about is that it's a pointer, but a pointer  is not of type `long`, in c you can convert from `void *` to any pointer type and from any pointer type to `void`. A pointer stores a value that is an address. But it's not a `long`.

Answer (score 9):

`%c` format specifier expects an argumnet of type `char`.

In your code, `*(&p)` is of type `char *`. Using `%c` to print that leads to [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Reference: From chapter 7.21.6.1, `C11` standard, paragraph 9,

> If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined. If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Thanks, great answer. Can you please give a link to your reference?

Comment: @KorayTugay You're welcome. I reffered to the `C11` standard document. An online draft version of the standard is available [here](http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf).